# create navigationbar dynamatically in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is the static navigation bar how i set in my project , but want to do in dynamic way, here is the two type of code...

```
viewsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    AfterloginViewController *toolsnavigation = [[AfterloginViewController alloc] init];
    toolsnavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cool.png"];
    [toolsnavigation setTitle:@"Tools"];
    UINavigationController *nav0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:toolsnavigation];

MapViewController *myridenavigation = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    myridenavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cool.png"];
    [myridenavigation setTitle:@"Login"];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myridenavigation];

viewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav0,nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5,nav6,nav7,nav8, nil];

    tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabbarController setViewControllers:viewsArray];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
```

Now i am getting data from the URL and want to assign it as dynamically navigation item. But i m puzzeled now, any idea how to do it.

```
NSString *loginstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@nvgationarray.php",mydomainurl];
    NSMutableData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: loginstring]];
    NSDictionary *allData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:nil];

    int i = 0;
    for(NSDictionary *stat in allData)
    {
        NSString *ssprst = [stat objectForKey:@"tab_type"];
        NSString *ssprst1 = [stat objectForKey:@"tab_name"];
        NSString *ssprst2 = [stat objectForKey:@"tab_id"];
        NSString *ssprst3 = [stat objectForKey:@"icon"];
        NSLog(@"all data ===== :::: %@ %@ %@ %@",ssprst,ssprst1,ssprst2,ssprst3);
        NSLog(@"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

        AbcViewController *myridenavigation = [[AbcViewController alloc] init];
        myridenavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cool.png"];
        [myridenavigation setTitle:@"Login"];
        UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myridenavigation];
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: do you want to assign data synchronously (wait until data receive then create navigationbar)? or asynchronously (no need to wait until data receive, do sth else, when data receive create navigationbar)

Comment: Data is receiving properly and now i have to assign in to the navigation controller..

Comment: so it's synchronous? Do you want to create a lots of uiviewcontroller or uinavigationcontroller? It's seems weird for me to create many uinavigationcontroller. Do you want to retain the memory of uinavigationcontroller or not?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retain memory `UINavigationController` . I suggest you hold it in `NSMutableArray`.

In header file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* arrayNavigationCont;
```

In implementation file

```
@synthesize arrayNavigationCont = _arrayNavigationCont;
```

do not forget also to init array in somewhere relevant like `viewDidLoad`

```
self.arrayNavigationCont = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In your method
...

```
for(NSDictionary *stat in allData)
{
        ...
        AbcViewController *myridenavigation = [[AbcViewController alloc] init];
        myridenavigation.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cool.png"];
        [myridenavigation setTitle:@"Login"];
        UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myridenavigation];
        [self.arrayNavigationCont addObject:nav1]
        i++;

}
```

Later you can access you navigationConts somewhere again

```
for(int i = 0; i < [self.arrayNavigationCont count]; i++)
{
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [self.arrayNavigationCont objectAtIndex:i];
    //do sth with nav1 to your like
}
```